# mvc2 asp.net find all records where conditions are met LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to query my Model to find all instances of "A" where a few conditions are true.

For instance, the following tables:

```
A
----
b_id
c_id
name

B
----
id
name

C
----
id
name
```

I want to perform a query to find all records from A where B.name == "foo" and C.name == "baz"

edit:

I am using Linq to Entites:

```
FooEntities db = new FooEntities();
```

Trying to do something like...

```
A FooA = db.As.Include("B").Include("C").Where(a => a.b_id == 1);
```

Comment: You marked this as MVC2 and ASP.NET, but your question appears to be about your data layer. What are you using to query these tables? SQL? LINQ to Entities? Provide the code you have so far so people have something to work from.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var As = db.As.Include("B").Include("C")
      .Where(a => a.B.name === "foo" && a.C.Name == "baz");
```